# Manipulate MP4 video with curl

Tags: php, curl, mp4

I am accessing a remote `.mp4` video using curl. I can display it in the browser, but the functions do not work correctly. The total minutes of the video do not appear and I can not advance or rewind the video.

What is responsible for these functions? The header? How can I make it work in curl?

My current script is this:

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
    header('Content-Disposition: filename="video.mp4"');

    $url = 'http://www.exemple.com/video.mp4';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: What? Are you doing? Requesting or responding?

Comment: I did not quite understand the question. I think I'm Requesting and responding

I am making a request to a remote server that has the video. And then returning the video to the person making the request.

Comment: Your script is just doing the work of a proxy. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: You want to display the total seconds/minutes of the video? https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the header

```
Content-Length
```

So the client knows how much of the data is remaining.

Also make sure your script acts as a **stream**, not that you read the whole file and print it back. Google for `php output buffering`. I don't think it causes your issue but it improves performance and server health tho.